# End a nested loop in Python

Tags: python, function, loops

We want make a package of goal kilos of chocolate.
We have small bars (1 kilo each) and big bars (5 kilos each).
Return the number of small bars to use, assuming we always use big bars before small bars.
Return -1 if it can't be done.

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    for i in range(1,big+1):
        for j in range(1,small+1):
            if sum(list((i*5,j*1))) == goal:
                return i
            else:
                return -1

    
make_chocolate(2,2,12)
```

The text above says it all: However, the function does not give the correct output. I always get -1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your loops are completely pointless; in all cases, you `return` on the very first iteration.  The `return -1` should probably be outside of both loops, so that it only happens if nothing is found.

Comment: In this case, the fix turns out to be fixing your indentation: you only want to return `-1` if the entire outer loop completes without `return i` being encountered, so that `else` should really be part of the outer `for` loop, not the `if` statement.

Comment: As an aside, `sum(list((i*5, j*1)))` is a confusing way to write `i*5 + j`.

Comment: The only way `-1` should be returned is if `goal` is a non-positive number, so you can simply check for that initially, and raise an *exception* instead of making the user decide if the return value is a valid number of small bars.

Comment: #jasonharper Your thinking seems to be along the same path as mine. I was going to suggest stepping through the loops on paper to understand the problem better. A bit old-school ... but a good learning tool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `-1` if *none* of the calls to `sum` produce the right answer. That means waiting until after the outer loop has completed. You can do this by making use of the `for` loop's `else` clause, which means the fix here is to simply dedent your `else`:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    for i in range(1,big+1):
        for j in range(1,small+1):
            if sum(list((i*5,j*1))) == goal:
                return i
    else:
        return -1
```

And because there is no code after the `for` loop, `return -1` can simply appear *after* the `for` loop, rather than as part of it.

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    for i in range(1,big+1):
        for j in range(1,small+1):
            if sum(list((i*5,j*1))) == goal:
                return i
    
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for loops, just use modulo and integer division:

```py
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    after_big = goal%big
    if after_big%small != 0:
        return -1
    return after_big//small
```

It the works well:

```
>>> make_chocolate(1,5,12)
2
```

Comment: Thanks. I don´t want to look at any answers before I complete the task. Sure, there are a lot more elegant answers than mine.